# Structuring TCP messages for correct data transfer

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

I'm writing a program in C# that has a server that transfers data between multiple clients. Right now whenever I need to send data, I send 4 bytes of length and length bytes of data, and whenever there is data available to read on the receiving end, it reads the first 4 bytes as the length and reads length amount of bytes as the data.

I was wondering if there might be a situation where a few bytes might be missed somehow and then I'd be stuck trying to read billions of bytes of nonexistent data because I read the wrong bytes as the length.

I thought of using a say a unique string and whenever that string is read, the 4 bytes of length is read after that, and then some sort of checksum, and then 4 bytes of a random ID, and then length amount of bytes is read. If those bytes don't pass the checksum or the unique string is found in it, then the message is discarded and a request is sent to resend the message by its ID, and the next message will be received starting from the next occurrence of the unique string.

Is this method good enough or should I do it some other way?

Comment: TCP has a checksum, and it guarantees data delivery, in the proper order. Learn about TCP before you start trying to create (redundant) TCP features.

Comment: @RonMaupin Oh okay so any data I send is guaranteed to be received?

Comment: You can read all about TCP from many locations, and _[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793)_ is the definition of TCP.

Comment: @ChrisK, that is actually incorrect. IP may fragment packets to fit the MTU at the network layer because fragmentation is built into IP, but TCP does not fragment. TCP segments data to fit the MSS. People often confuse those things, but the difference is very important.

Comment: I think the tcp will guarantee that the data will received completely as @Ron Maupin said, unlike udp. As you can use a kind of marker at the of packets to tell you that's the end of packets. Just like you are reading the length of data before you read the data, add some more bytes in the end of packet to tell you that's the end of packets. and when you read chunks. just read the end of chunk which will tell you if there is more data or not. If you got the end of data marker, then do whatever you want with those data.

Comment: @kaj That approach compromises what data you can actually send.  Suppose that data contains `<EOF>`?

Comment: @kaj This *not* a viable solution to the OP's problem, for the reasons I just gave.  He already _has_ a viable solution, please drop this.  The approach in that link is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a so-called *Transport Layer Protocol*.  You can read a handy primer about what guarantees that gives you [here](http://bpastudio.csudh.edu/fac/lpress/471/hout/netech/tcpintro.htm).

This in turn implies that all the data you transmit will be reliably received, in the same order it was sent.  If anything gets dropped or corrupted in transit, TCP will resend it.  That all happens under the covers and you don't need to worry about it.  It also handles flow control.

The only thing out of the ordinary that you have to do is to handle the connection dropping unexpectedly.  Apart from that (or maybe you're already doing it) the approach you have there is fine, although it is traditional to put those length bytes out on the wire in so-called network byte order, which is big-endian.  I don't know how you would do that in C# but the C routines that support this are described [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl).  But for what you're doing you probably don't need to bother.